# Publishing from Visual Studio and .NET Core servicing updates, what is the best way to resolve?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to use the Publishing tool from Visual Studio 2017. However, I guess Microsoft is now pushing out "servicing updates" for .NET core. It's complaining about a RuntimeIdentifier property being set during build or publish but not during restore. I didn't change anything. The Deployment Mode is set to Self Contained, so it should just include all dependencies and publish it to the server, right?

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       NETSDK1061: The project was restored using Microsoft.NETCore.App version 2.1.3, but with current settings, version 2.1.3-servicing-26724-03 would be used instead. To resolve this issue, make sure the same settings are used for restore and for subsequent operations such as build or publish. Typically this issue can occur if the RuntimeIdentifier property is set during build or publish but not during restore.

Comment: So not sure what's the real issue? Are you getting errors on VS while running Publish?

Comment: Included the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in ***VS2017 "15.8.2"***. Please see the answer to [[VS2017 15.8.2 publishing error (.NET Core 2.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52098812/vs2017-15-8-2-publishing-error-net-core-2-1])