# NETSDK1061: The project was restored using Microsoft.NETCore.App version 1.0.0, but with current settings, version 2.0.9 would be used instead

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, visual-studio-app-center

I'm developing a mobile app and using MS App Center for CI. Yesterday the Unit Test project failed to build in App Center with the following error. I couldn't recreate the issue on any developer machine, this error only occurs in App Center.

> error : NETSDK1061: The project was restored using
> Microsoft.NETCore.App version 1.0.0, but with current settings,
> version 2.0.9 would be used instead. To resolve this issue, make sure
> the same settings are used for restore and for subsequent operations
> such as build or publish. Typically this issue can occur if the
> RuntimeIdentifier property is set during build or publish but not
> during restore. For more information, see
> https://aka.ms/dotnet-runtime-patch-selection.

Their paid support just give the basics, clean the project, roll back my last commit etc. Has anyone come into this issue before on App Center?

Comment: easiest way to avoid this issue is to build using the same configuration that you want to publish using and then run
dotnet publish --no-restore -r win10-x64 or whatever runtime you expect to publish to

Comment: I can't control the commands used by App Center, it's a SaaS-based CI.

Comment: you may have to raise it with somebody who does have control then

Comment: If this is the only way to fix then it's likely a problem with their platform yes. Is there some way to control the configuration in the csproj  or sln files?

Answer (score 37):

You need to set the same publish and building runtimes

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.1.0</RuntimeFrameworkVersion> --> fix publishing issues
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget> --> fix publishing issues
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Update="Microsoft.NETCore.App" Version="2.1.0" /> --> fix building issues
    <ProjectReference Include="..\PublicSonar.Monitor.Persistent.Json\PublicSonar.Monitor.Persistent.Json.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Hi Paul, could you possibly elaborate for this answer please, I get this problem after running a publish as a self hosting executable, does that quietly swap out the target SDK? The solution you suggested was simple and straight forward and worked, so thank you

Comment: Where is this XML from?

Comment: from csproj file

Answer (score 12):

If you use Azure DevOps, don't edit project file. Use "dotnet restore"(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops) instead of Nuget restore:

Replace this:

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
```

With this:

```
- script: dotnet restore
```

Answer (score 8):

I am on Visual Studio 2019. I encountered this issue when I tried to publish my project as Self-contained for the second time.

What I did to get rid of this error was:

- Change the Deployment Mode to Framework Dependent
- Publish the project
- Change it back to Self-contained and published again

It seemed to be caused by some faulty cache that can be cleared by switching to a different deployment mode.

Comment: This helped me!

Comment: This worked on VS2022.

Comment: Had the same Problem: Although I added `<TargetLatestRuntimePatch>true</TargetLatestRuntimePatch>` to every Project I still received `NTSDK1061 publish error: The project was restored using`.
Changing the Mode briefly fixed it! Thank you,

Answer (score 5):

Try Adding `<TargetLatestRuntimePatch>true</TargetLatestRuntimePatch>`to your `<PropertyGroup>` tag. Example :

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    <TargetLatestRuntimePatch>true</TargetLatestRuntimePatch>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: The only solution that worked for me. Thanks for saving my day!

Answer (score 5):

Add this in the .csproj

```
<PropertyGroup>
<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.1.5</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: This made my day..oops night!

Comment: `<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.0.0</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>` did it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am on Visual Studio 2019 and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52100563/706555) put me on the right path, my procedure was:

- Uninstall all instances of `Microsoft .NET Core SDK` off my machine.
- Restarted computer.
- Installed latest version of the `SDK` from [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.1).

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because I had a **nuget source that was no longer existing**. After removing the faulty nuget source I restored the project and everything worked.

I restored the project via commandline:

```
dotnet restore
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when building in Azure Devops and none of the other answers would fix it. My Build and Publish steps already had matching `--runtime` options.

The fix for me turned out to be to add the following into the the `.csproj` file (substitute the `RuntimeIdentifier` with the correct one for your deployment scenario):

```
  <PropertyGroup>
      ...
      <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check also the solution I suggested here ([Using Azure Pipelines with multi targeting projects I get error NETSDK1061](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57617442/using-azure-pipelines-with-multi-targeting-projects-i-get-error-netsdk1061/57623556?noredirect=1#comment101702667_57623556)), maybe it works for you, too:

```
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '>=4.3.0'
    checkLatest: true
```

Answer (score 0):

What solved the issue for me, was to update the default NuGet package cache 'C:\Users\.nuget\packages' used for restore by changing the parameter in msvc:

Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > Package Restore > Allow NuGet to download missing package & Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio.